# Calculate Point collision between a point of a given vector and the edge of a Circle

Tags: math, geometry, angle

Lets say I have a point within a circle(not necessarily the origin) moving at a given vector how would I calculate the x and y coordinate of the point where it hits the edge of the circle.

Comment: Pythagoras' theorem may be useful

Comment: Maybe this is a better question for the math stack exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift all coordinates by -cx, -cy. Now circle is centered at origin and has equation

```
x^2+y^2=R^2
```

Point coordinate (px, py), unit direction vector is (dx,dy). Equation of ray:

```
x = px + t * dx
y = py + t * dy
```

Substitute these variables into the circle equation, solve equation, find parameter t>0, then find intersection point (x,y), shift it back by (cx, cy).

Comment: I am sorry but I am still a little lost could you show me the steps with these examples. origin(0,0) vector 5,5 point 1,1 radius 3.84 and another for origin(0,0) vector 5,5 point 0,0 radius 3.84.  I would really appriciate it even though you have done so much already.  Also what does t represent.

Comment: `(1+5*t)^2+(1+5*t)^2=3.84^2; 2+20t+50t^2=14.74;  50t^2+20t-12.74=0; Disrcriminant~=2959; t1~=0.34; x~=2.7 y~=2.7`  t is unknown parameter in parametric representation of straight line